# Apache Rewrite doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have tried this under windows / xampp and it worked:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want that all links work like this

```
<a href="/customers">Customers</a>
```

For that I have in my index.php this script:

```
$page =   array_filter( explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) );
```

And then I work with **$page** like this

```
if(!empty($page)) {

    switch($page[1])
    {
        case 'customers';
            require_once('customers.php');      
        break;
```

After it worked under Windows I tried it on a Debian Apache / PHP7 Server, but I get always a 404 error.
And I don't know why. The Rewrite Modul is loaded.

**Update**
Changed

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

and it works now.
Thanks